# SQL: Return true if condition is met only one time in query

Tags: sql, data-analysis

I have both a log of actions made by users:

| Action ID | User | Action date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 07:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-01-01 13:00 |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-01-02 05:00 |
| 4 | 1 | 2023-01-02 16:00 |
| 5 | 2 | 2023-06-15 04:00 |
| 6 | 2 | 2023-06-15 09:00 |

and a log of "managed" states for the same users:

| Log entry ID | User | MGMT started at | MGMT ended at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 06:58 | 2023-01-01 07:02 |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-01-01 11:58 | 2023-01-01 16:02 |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-01-02 15:58 | 2023-01-02 17:02 |
| 4 | 2 | 2023-06-15 03:58 | 2023-06-15 04:02 |
| 5 | 2 | 2023-06-15 08:58 | 2023-06-15 09:02 |

I want to know which users have performed an action while being in a non-managed state. My intended result would look kinda like this:

| User | Action ID | Action state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Managed |
| 1 | 2 | Managed |
| 1 | 3 | Not managed |
| 1 | 4 | Managed |
| 2 | 5 | Managed |
| 2 | 6 | Managed |

However, when running my SQL query, which roughly looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM actionlogs
JOIN mgmtlogs ON actionlogs.User = mgmtlogs.User
ORDER BY Action ID
```

I get results like this:

| User | MGMT started at | MGMT ended at | Action ID | Action date | Action state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 06:58 | 2023-01-01 07:02 | 1 | 2023-01-01 07:00 | Managed |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 11:58 | 2023-01-01 16:02 | 1 | 2023-01-01 07:00 | Not managed |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 15:58 | 2023-01-02 17:02 | 1 | 2023-01-01 07:00 | Not managed |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 06:58 | 2023-01-01 07:02 | 2 | 2023-01-01 13:00 | Not managed |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 11:58 | 2023-01-01 16:02 | 2 | 2023-01-01 13:00 | Managed |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 15:58 | 2023-01-02 17:02 | 2 | 2023-01-01 13:00 | Not managed |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 06:58 | 2023-01-01 07:02 | 3 | 2023-01-02 05:00 | Not managed |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 11:58 | 2023-01-01 16:02 | 3 | 2023-01-02 05:00 | Not managed |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 15:58 | 2023-01-02 17:02 | 3 | 2023-01-02 05:00 | Not managed |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 06:58 | 2023-01-01 07:02 | 4 | 2023-01-02 16:00 | Not managed |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 11:58 | 2023-01-01 16:02 | 4 | 2023-01-02 16:00 | Not managed |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 15:58 | 2023-01-02 17:02 | 4 | 2023-01-02 16:00 | Managed |
| 2 | 2023-06-15 03:58 | 2023-06-15 04:02 | 5 | 2023-06-15 04:00 | Managed |
| 2 | 2023-06-15 08:58 | 2023-06-15 09:02 | 5 | 2023-06-15 04:00 | Not managed |
| 2 | 2023-06-15 03:58 | 2023-06-15 04:02 | 6 | 2023-06-15 09:00 | Not managed |
| 2 | 2023-06-15 08:58 | 2023-06-15 09:02 | 6 | 2023-06-15 09:00 | Managed |

Which leads me to the following issue: when trying to sort between actions made by my users while in "managed" mode (i.e. between the start and end timestamps), my queries always end up checking every action date againts each recorded "managed" time bracket, ending up telling me that they are both "managed" and "not managed". But as I see it, if the action date meets the condition of being in any of the recorded brackets, the action should be considered as "managed" only and the other checks should be ignored. Is it possible to perform this in proper SQL syntax?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please show us what youe expected results *are*, not what they're *not*

Comment: Hi, please explain simply what you want to achieve, it is difficult to understand, non-managed is actions are not in mgtlog table and not between MGMT started at and  MGMT ended at?

Comment: I've edited in some more info, hopefully this wiil be more useful

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `NOT EXISTS` which will be able to find the records from `actionlogs` for which there is no matching data available in `mgmtlogs` table as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM actionlogs a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (select 1 from mgmtlogs m
    WHERE a.User = m.User
      AND a.actiondate between m.mgmt_started_at and m.mgmt_ended_at)
ORDER BY a.actionid
```